# Proving the implication $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n a_{n+1} =0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence such that for all $n$, $a_n>0$. I have to prove that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n a_{n+1} =0$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$. Here's my reasoning: $\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists k$ such that $\forall n>k$ we have $|a_n a_{n+1}|=a_n a_{n+1} < \varepsilon$ and thus $a_n=|a_n|=|a_n-0| < \frac{\varepsilon}{a_{n+1}} \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$. However I don't feel comfortable with the $a_{n+1}$ on the r.h.s. What do you think?

Comment: This isn't true without some further assumptions. For example, take $a_n = 1$ for $n$ even and $a_{2k+1} = \frac{1}{k}$.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it holds. For example, Let $a_{2n}=\frac 1n,a_{2n+1}=\sqrt n$.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed there must be a mistake. By the way, what was the flow in my reasoning?

Comment: @user227087 In fact, I don't understand your reasoning...Why $a_n< \frac{\varepsilon}{a_{n+1}}$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$?

Comment: Well, because we can control the $\varepsilon/a_{n+1}$ by picking any $\varepsilon$ that we like. So the term $\varepsilon/a_{n+1}$ itself is like a "$\varepsilon$" in any regular proof of limit.

Comment: @user227087 Well, I think to prove the existence of limit, you should **fix** $\varepsilon$ each time, but not **vary** it to control $a_n$.

Comment: @CensLI - but we need $a_n<\varepsilon'$ for all $\varepsilon'$. What's important is the $\varepsilon'$ which is indeed fixed. Once it is fixed, we can find $\varepsilon$ that will satisfy $\varepsilon/a_{n+1}<\varepsilon'$ and thus $a_n<\varepsilon'$.

Comment: @user227087 But then you need to choose a $\varepsilon$ such that **all but finite** $\varepsilon/a_{n+1}$ is bounded by $<\varepsilon'$. To make it you need not only control $\varepsilon$, but also estimate the upper bound of $|\frac 1{a_n}|$

Comment: why not simply set $\varepsilon=\lfloor \varepsilon' a_{n+1}\rfloor$? Then for all but a finite $n$ we'll have $a_n<\frac{\lfloor \varepsilon' a_{n+1}\rfloor}{a_{n+1}}\leq\varepsilon'$, which is exactly what we need for the sequence $\{a_n\}$ to converge to $0$. Thanks in advance. (understanding the issue is very important to me).

Comment: @user227087 You use $\lfloor \varepsilon' a_{n+1}\rfloor$ to denote the infimum of $\{\varepsilon' a_{n+1}\}$? It may well be $0$ (just as my counterexample), in that case, you cannot find a positive $\varepsilon$.

Comment: It is the floor function. Yes it can be zero, you're right. But what if we do something more complicated. For example: $\varepsilon=\varepsilon' a_{n+1}/2$. It is less than $\varepsilon' a_{n+1}$ but also bigger than zero.

Comment: @user227087 For each fixed $\varepsilon'$, you need to find a **fixed** $\varepsilon$ to correspond to that fixed $\varepsilon'$.

Comment: I understand that it is not fixed because of $a_{n+1}$. But I still don't understand why do we care if $\varepsilon$ is fixed or not. The definition of limit doesn't care what we do as long as we can ensure that (for all $\varepsilon'>0$) $a_n<\varepsilon'$ for all but a finite $n$. We know that **for all** $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $a_n<\varepsilon/a_{n+1}$. If you give me any $\varepsilon'>0$ I can provide you $N$ and $\varepsilon$ such that for all $n>N$, $a_n<\varepsilon'$.

Comment: Just to clarify, $\varepsilon'>0$ must be fixed, I agree. But why should $\varepsilon$?

Comment: @user227087 The reason is that  we have to find a fixed $N$ for each fixed $\varepsilon'$. And a fixed $\varepsilon$ helps us to find such a $N$. If you vary $\varepsilon$ as you want, you have to examine carefully the dependence of $N(\varepsilon)$ on $\varepsilon$, (that is, how fast the selected $N(\varepsilon)$ will grow as $\varepsilon$ grow) and demonstrate that we have a uniform $N$. Now that you are given an arbitrary sequence, you know nothing about the the relationship between $\varepsilon$ and $N$ , so I think to do such an analysis is hopeless.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**  $a_{2n}=\frac{1}{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1} =\sqrt{2n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

As said that's not correct. I think you should better argue by contradiction that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq 0$. WLOG the limit exists and $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=l>0\Rightarrow \lim a_na_{n+1}=l^2>0$$ in contradiction which means that necessarily $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ .

Answer (score 0):

if limit exist then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}$ thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_na_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}^2=0$ thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ if limit does not exist we cannot comment on $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this property doesn't hold. The flaw in your reasoning is the inequality that ${\varepsilon \over a_{n+1}}<\varepsilon$, you're assuming $a_{n+1}>1$, which you don't necessarily know. You can have $a_k<1$ for infinitely many $k$, which is what goes wrong with the examples given by other posters.

Added:

The definition of limit says: $\left ( \forall \varepsilon ' >0 \right )\left (  \exists N \right )\left ( \forall n>N \right )\left (  |a_n -L|<\varepsilon \right )$. 
Let $\varepsilon '>0$ be given. If you fix some natural number $k$, you can set $\varepsilon = \left \lfloor\varepsilon ' |a_k| \right \rfloor$ to obtain an $N$ such that for all $n>N$: $|a_na_{n+1}|<\varepsilon$ which gives $|a_n|<{\varepsilon \over |a_{n+1}|}$. But notice that we have the **fixed** subindex $k$ in the numerator and $n+1$ in the denominator, so we cannot conclude anything further.

What you cannot do is set $\varepsilon=\left \lfloor |a_n| \varepsilon' \right \rfloor$ for all $n$ since this isn't a number, it is a function of $n$. And if you were to try to work around this by taking, for example $\varepsilon =\displaystyle \inf _{n \in \mathbb{N}}\left \lfloor |a_n| \varepsilon' \right \rfloor$ you have no guarantee that this is a positive number.

Comment: I don't understand why it matters if $a_{n+1}>1$ or not. Here's how my book proves the theorem $\lim_{n\to\infty}c a_n =c\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ for $c\neq 0$: $\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists N,\forall n>N:|a_n-L|<\frac{\varepsilon}{|c|}\implies|c||a_n-L|<\varepsilon\implies|ca_n-cL|=|c(a_n-L)|<\varepsilon$. We can go backwards in this case and here we have $\varepsilon/|c|$ even though it can be that $|c|<1$. How is that different from our case? Why $a_{n+1}$ must be greater than 1?

Comment: You cannot conclude that ${\varepsilon \over a_{n+1}}<\varepsilon$ if you do not know that $a_{n+1}>1$. Does ${\varepsilon \over 0.5}<\varepsilon$? 
The theorem you brought up is different because $c$ is a fixed number, and as such we can take $|a_n-L|<{\varepsilon \over |c|}$ from the get go, and hence you get $|c(a_n-l)|<|c||{\varepsilon \over c}|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: By the way, I don't claim that $\varepsilon/a_{n+1}<\varepsilon$. I claim that $\varepsilon'=\varepsilon/a_{n+1}$ is an "epsilon by itself". Just like $\varepsilon/|c|$ in the previous example.

Comment: You cannot take $|a_n-L|<{\varepsilon \over a_{n}}$ for all $n$ since the expression on the right depends on $n$, and is not fixed like ${\varepsilon \over c}$.

Comment: sorry for the dumb questions, but I really want to understand this. The definition of limit tells us that given any $\varepsilon'>0$ we must provide a number $N$ such that $\forall n>N: |a_n-L|<\varepsilon'$. In our case $\forall\varepsilon'>0$ we can give $N=k$ and by setting $\varepsilon=\lfloor\varepsilon'a_{n+1}\rfloor$ we have $|a_n|<(\lfloor\varepsilon'a_{n+1}\rfloor)/a_{n+1}<\varepsilon'$. Why is it wrong? How's the fact that $a_{n+1}$ isn't fixed changes the rules of the game?

Comment: Check my edit. Does that help?